# Quitting Java program renders Mac OS X window switching non-functional

Tags: java, macos, swing

On the Mac where I do my programming, I have an app installed called [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.net) that allows me to bind keyboard shortcuts to 'gestures' on my trackpad. I have bound a gesture (that doesn't have an Apple default) to the shortcut <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, which quits the active program. I have found this very convenient for quickly quitting programs that I am testing, so that I can get back to writing code.

However for the graphical game that I am programming, this action makes it so that I can't use a three finger swipe to switch between windows (several other gestures are also disabled). This will also happen if I go up to the menu and click quit or if I click the red x close button. The fix is to either restart my computer or (and this is really weird) to click the in-game close button which calls `System.exit(0);`. I know that most players will be using this but I still want to figure out why this is happening. In addition games like Minecraft on my computer don't do this.

I am using a `JFrame` with `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` in the code. In an attempt to fix the issue I have tried registering a `com.apple.eawt.QuitHandler` that calls `System.exit(0);` in the handler.

I have no idea what would be considered relevant code here, so whatever you would like to see, just let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. There was one rouge `Thread.sleep()` call in my `JFrame` that was somehow effecting my system.